# Javascript filter null object properties

Tags: javascript

I have an Array with one or more objects and I want to filter out all null properties:

```js
asset = [{"ObjId":177791,"ObjCreditlineM":"DEU","ObjReprorechtM":null,"ObjKommentarM":null,"ObjZustandM":null,"ObjReserve01M":null,"ObjReserve02M":null,"ObjFeld01M":null,"ObjFeld02M":null,"ObjFeld03M":null,"ObjFeld04M":"Foto","ObjFeld05M":null,"ObjFeld06M":null,"ObjFeld07M":null,"ObjFeld01S":null,"ObjFeld02S":null,"ObjFeld03S":null,"ObjFeld04S":null,"ObjFeld05S":null,"ObjFeld06S":null,"ObjFeld07S":null,"ObjFeld01F":0,"ObjFeld02F":0,"ObjFeld01D":null,"ObjFeld02D":null,"ObjInv01S":null,"ObjInv02S":null,"ObjInv03S":null,"ObjInv04S":null,"ObjInv05S":null,"ObjInv06S":null,"ObjDinId":0,"ObjReferenz01Id":null,"ObjReferenz02Id":null,"ObjTransferId":null,"ObjGesperrtS":null,"ObjIconTextM":null}]


// My attempt:

var filledProps = asset.map(el => { 
  if (Object.keys(el)) { // check if object property value is not null
    return el;
  };
});

console.log(filledProps);
```

But I get the same object properties back. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a new array with new objects that only have the properties that aren't `null` from the original. Is so, `map` is where you want to start, but `Object.keys(el)` is always truthy, since it returns an array of property names. You're close though:

```js
var asset = [{"ObjId":177791,"ObjCreditlineM":"DEU","ObjReprorechtM":null,"ObjKommentarM":null,"ObjZustandM":null,"ObjReserve01M":null,"ObjReserve02M":null,"ObjFeld01M":null,"ObjFeld02M":null,"ObjFeld03M":null,"ObjFeld04M":"Foto","ObjFeld05M":null,"ObjFeld06M":null,"ObjFeld07M":null,"ObjFeld01S":null,"ObjFeld02S":null,"ObjFeld03S":null,"ObjFeld04S":null,"ObjFeld05S":null,"ObjFeld06S":null,"ObjFeld07S":null,"ObjFeld01F":0,"ObjFeld02F":0,"ObjFeld01D":null,"ObjFeld02D":null,"ObjInv01S":null,"ObjInv02S":null,"ObjInv03S":null,"ObjInv04S":null,"ObjInv05S":null,"ObjInv06S":null,"ObjDinId":0,"ObjReferenz01Id":null,"ObjReferenz02Id":null,"ObjTransferId":null,"ObjGesperrtS":null,"ObjIconTextM":null}]

// Use `map` to get a new array with new objects
var filledProps = asset.map(el => {
  // Loop the property names of `el`, creating a new object
  // with the ones whose values aren't `null`.
  // `reduce` is commonly used for doing this:
  return Object.keys(el).reduce((newObj, key) => {
    const value = el[key];
    if (value !== null) {
      newObj[key] = value;
    }
    return newObj;
  }, {});
});
console.log(filledProps);
```

> What am I missing?

Since `if (Object.keys(el))` is always truthy, your code was just always returning `el` unchanged. It wasn't creating a new object, or deleting properties with `null` values from the original object.

The above creates new objects, but if you like, you can just delete properties from the originals that have `null` values instead:

```js
var asset = [{"ObjId":177791,"ObjCreditlineM":"DEU","ObjReprorechtM":null,"ObjKommentarM":null,"ObjZustandM":null,"ObjReserve01M":null,"ObjReserve02M":null,"ObjFeld01M":null,"ObjFeld02M":null,"ObjFeld03M":null,"ObjFeld04M":"Foto","ObjFeld05M":null,"ObjFeld06M":null,"ObjFeld07M":null,"ObjFeld01S":null,"ObjFeld02S":null,"ObjFeld03S":null,"ObjFeld04S":null,"ObjFeld05S":null,"ObjFeld06S":null,"ObjFeld07S":null,"ObjFeld01F":0,"ObjFeld02F":0,"ObjFeld01D":null,"ObjFeld02D":null,"ObjInv01S":null,"ObjInv02S":null,"ObjInv03S":null,"ObjInv04S":null,"ObjInv05S":null,"ObjInv06S":null,"ObjDinId":0,"ObjReferenz01Id":null,"ObjReferenz02Id":null,"ObjTransferId":null,"ObjGesperrtS":null,"ObjIconTextM":null}];

asset.forEach(el => {
  Object.keys(el).forEach(key => {
    if (el[key] === null) {
      delete el[key];
    }
  });
});
console.log(asset);
```

Two aspects of that to call out, though:

- It modifies the original objects (and thus, in a way, the original array).
- When you delete a property from an object, it can have an impact on the performance of property lookup on that object afterward. 99.999% of the time you don't care, but it's there.

Answer (score 3):

```js
asset = [{"ObjId":177791,"ObjCreditlineM":"DEU","ObjReprorechtM":null,"ObjKommentarM":null,"ObjZustandM":null,"ObjReserve01M":null,"ObjReserve02M":null,"ObjFeld01M":null,"ObjFeld02M":null,"ObjFeld03M":null,"ObjFeld04M":"Foto","ObjFeld05M":null,"ObjFeld06M":null,"ObjFeld07M":null,"ObjFeld01S":null,"ObjFeld02S":null,"ObjFeld03S":null,"ObjFeld04S":null,"ObjFeld05S":null,"ObjFeld06S":null,"ObjFeld07S":null,"ObjFeld01F":0,"ObjFeld02F":0,"ObjFeld01D":null,"ObjFeld02D":null,"ObjInv01S":null,"ObjInv02S":null,"ObjInv03S":null,"ObjInv04S":null,"ObjInv05S":null,"ObjInv06S":null,"ObjDinId":0,"ObjReferenz01Id":null,"ObjReferenz02Id":null,"ObjTransferId":null,"ObjGesperrtS":null,"ObjIconTextM":null}]

var filledProps = asset.map(el => { 
   var obj = {};
   for(var prop in el) {
      if(el[prop] !== null) {
          obj[prop] = el[prop];
      }
   }
   return obj;
});

console.log(filledProps);
```